# How to insert a list of json string into an array dict?

Tags: python, json

I have an array (list of json string) and I want to move the whole array into a dict array.
I know how to change 1 of this json string into dict. But Is it possible to change the whole list?
my list as below:

```
a[0] = {"name": "May", "age": "99", "gender": "Female"}
a[1] = {"name": "Ray", "age": "88", "gender": "male"}
a[2] = {"name": "Tim", "age": "23", "gender": "male"}
```

When I want to change a[0] into dict, I use the code as below:

```
res = json.loads(a[0])
```

But when I want to change all of it into a array dict, it happen as below:

```
res[0] = json.loads(a[0])
```

error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "td.py", line 44, in <module>
    res[x] = json.loads(a[x])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting object: line 1 column 2063 (char 2062)
```

Comment: first you have to create dictionary - `res = dict()` to put value `res[0] = json.loads(a[0])`. OR create and put value in one line - `res = {0:  json.loads(a[0])}`

Comment: `a[0]` is already a Python dict, not a JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’d need to initialise the dictionary first

e.g

res = {}

Before

Setting res[0] = ...